# neovim installation via asdf -- reshim issues

Tags: neovim, asdf

```
➜ asdf which neovim
unknown command: neovim. Perhaps you have to reshim?
➜ asdf current neovim
neovim          ref:master      /Users/abhishektripathi/.tool-versions
➜ asdf reshim neovim
➜ asdf which neovim
unknown command: neovim. Perhaps you have to reshim?
➜ nvim
zsh: command not found: nvim
```

I installed neovim via asdf and cannot find neovim.
This is the output of my terminal. Which is very strange for me.

Any leads?

EDIT: using MacOS, ZSH, tmux. asdf was installed via brew.

Answer (score 2):

Just for archival purpose,

I removed and reinstalled neovim via

`asdf uninstall neovim ref:master`

`asdf install neovim ref:master`

That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The correct command is: `asdf which nvim`

Comment: ```
➜  ~ asdf which nvim  
unknown command: nvim. Perhaps you have to reshim?
➜  ~ asdf reshim nvim
No such plugin: nvim```

Comment: Your question was "Any leads?". Hopefully this helped you solve the problem :)

Comment: Yeah. Your comment did help. It made me wonder about my installation and it worked after a fresh install. Thanks!